# Difference between vcgencmd get_camera and raspi-config nonint get_camera?

Tags: pi-3b+, camera, i2c, raspbian-buster

I'm trying to figure out why everytime I poweroff and back on my device I need to manually enable the camera so I ran these 2 functions to get more insight on the situation.

For vcgencmd get_camera im getting supported=1 detected=0

For raspi-config nonint get_camera I'm getting 0 which means its on according to https://pi3g.com/2021/05/20/enabling-and-checking-i2c-on-the-raspberry-pi-using-the-command-line-for-your-own-scripts/

I'm not really understanding how this makes any sense so whats the difference between the two commands?

Comment: `raspi-config nonint get_camera`: just did a search on the page you linked to and I cannot find any reference to `get_camera`. Are you sure it means what you think it does? Please find a definite reference that supports your view.

Comment: See https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspi-config/blob/master/raspi-config#L1686. On Buster it looks as if it only checks if it's supported (start_x defined in config.txt) so there is no difference between both methods. It's a bit more complicated on Bullseye